# Safe scripts inside a python webapplication

Tags: python, programming-languages, embed, pyparsing

I want to give users ability to write simple scripts, which will be executed often in background.

Simplest solution could be just eval(), but it is really dangerous and uses too much resources. And yes, I know that eval isn't a solution ANYWAY.

So, next solution - use different interpreter in sandbox mode. Also, code should be executed within 1 second or it should be killed. Too much work and headache, don't you think so?

But really, I need not too much: I need calculator with ability to use conditions and return different numbers(or even strings) on different conditions. For example:

```
10 if a > 40
50 + c if (a + c) == 100
upgrade if 1/b > 40
42
```

Or similar. So, I think it is a good chance to write simple language from scratch! But yea, not really from scratch, there should be tools for this situation. First one was **pyparsing**, which looks really good! But it is a bit old and strange to use. For example, [simple rules with simple code](https://gist.github.com/iorlas/f8a60fa97c55493fd7aa) parsed in 7 seconds!

I'm a bit exhausted, can you suggest anything or tell your success story in similar situation?

Comment: Check out http://pyvideo.org/video/2585/building-and-breaking-a-python-sandbox by Jessica McKellar from PyCon 2014.  Should give you some ideas for what you'd need.

Comment: Or run it on GAE's secure environment remotely; like with http://eval.appspot.com/

Comment: Try adding `ParserElement.enablePackrat()` on the line right after importing pyparsing. Packrat optimization is significant when you use an infixNotation element with many levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comments about adding packrat parsing,

```
from pyparsing import *
ParserElement.enablePackrat()
```

here are some other suggestions for your code:

As much as I like constructing parsers from lower-level objects as a core feature of pyparsing, some things like decimal numbers are so low-level that all the pyparsing objects really slow things down.  To parse real numbers, you are better off performance-wise in creating a Regex that describes your pattern. (This is also a little tighter than your current Word(nums+'.-'), which would accept any character group of digits, '.'s, and '-'s):

```
number = Regex(r'-?\d+(\.\d*)?').setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: float(t[0]))
```

Now your percent expression makes more sense if you reuse `number` as part of the definition (since number already converts from string to float, compatible with Percent's initializer):

```
percent = (number + Suppress('%')).setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: Percent(t[0]))
```

Your definition of operation precedence had some errors - there is no precedence within comparison operations '<' '>' and so on, although you had them at multiple precedence levels in the arguments to infix notation.  You also show a `a > b > c` Python-like form of inequality, and I think this might be best supported as a ternary operation. See changes below:

```
operand = percent | number
inequalities = oneOf("< > >= <=")
expr = infixNotation(operand, [
    (oneOf('* /'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    (oneOf('+ -'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ((inequalities,inequalities), 3, opAssoc.LEFT),
    (inequalities, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    (oneOf('AND and && &'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    (oneOf('OR or || |'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using pypy's sandboxing features: http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html